# Separate Microphone and Audio

Tags: xbox-360, voice-chat

Ok so this will be the first asked question related to this at all: I crashed recently and lost my hearing, but I have a hearing aid that can connect to the audio with a phonak tvlink that I got. I want to do voice chat with my brother but I can't figure it out... all I can do is hear his voice and actually understand all of it somehow (go modern hearing aids!!).

How can I (if it's even possible) separate a mic from a system that let's me listen to voice chat and possibly the gameplay as well as talking to them across the voice chat system? And/or is there something that connects with bluetooth to both or something...? If you don't understand my awful writing, Google "Phonak TVlink S" and try to figure out how I could do full voice chat with it. The game is Black Ops 2 if that has any relevance.

Comment: We have a comment system that alerts you when someone asks for clarification, so that's covered for you!  My question to you is - are we talking about a Xbox or PS3 game, or a PC game?

Comment: Xbox 360 my bad. I'm new here.

Answer (score 2):

There's a couple of approaches that might work for you.

The first thing I would try is changing your voice preferences:

- Press the Guide button (the "Xbox button" in the middle of the controller)
- Navigate right to Settings
- Choose Preferences, then Voice
- Where it says Voice Output, choose "Play Through Both"

This will route the voice chat to your TV or home theater's speakers.  If you plug your hearing aid into the TV, you should hear the game sounds and the voice chat.  You can plug a standard Xbox 360 headset into the controller, but you can ignore the earpiece - the audio is routed to your TV.  Just speak into the mic as normal and you should hear everything fine through your aid.

The other thing you can try is buying a third-party headset or headset adapter.  Many headsets designed for the Xbox 360 (like Turtle Beach models that advertise compatibility) will route both the voice and the game audio to the headset by design.  However, interfacing your hearing aid to these might be tricky.

I own, use, and love my [Astro Mixamp](http://www.astrogaming.com/mixamp-pro-2013-edition).  They don't sell the wireless model without a headset anymore, but the wired model might work fine for you.  It plugs into the TV's optical out port, and then a standard headset can be plugged into the other end.  You can probably use your hearing aid as the audio out portion, and then plug any standard PC mic into the audio in jack.  It's more expensive, but if you're going to be doing this long term, it might be a more general solution to your issue.

Answer (score 2):

Something [like this](http://dx.com/p/xbox-360-voice-headset-port-to-2-regular-3-5mm-earphone-microphone-ports-converter-21993) should work for you. It breaks the controller port out into separate microphone and headphone standard 3.5" jacks. You would plug the headphone one into your Phonak TVlink and then the microphone in to a standard xbox headset, or some other standalone microphone. You should then be able to hear through your hearing aid and talk through the additional microphone.

I'm not recommending this one in particular, and there are plenty of 3rd party versions available on ebay and such.